# -Python 3- Console giving wrong output?

Tags: python

I am just re-learning Python at the moment, but I have encountered a problem for a very basic inventory system, when I press run and type "No" or "no", it still prints out the len function, any help?

[click here to see an image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip1zQ.png)

Comment: Please post your code as actual code. No one has fun retyping things from an image.

Comment: It should be `a == "Yes" or a == "yes"` in if. Same for elif.

Comment: Also, please add your code in text format from now on

Comment: your `if` statement is written in human logic not computer logic, to explain better your if statement is getting checked at `a=="Yes"` and if you type in anything else then it wont meet the criteria but the `or "yes"` will always evaluate to `True` because it isnt being checked against anything

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @languitar I don't think embedding that giant image into the question body improves things.

Comment: @PM2Ring "enter image description here" also isn't convincing to find code behind the link ;)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values

Comment: @languitar Fair point, so I've improved the link text. Ideally, Lorenzo would post the actual code as text, but I guess that's unlikely to happen now that I've closed the question.

Comment: @PM2Ring I just have the feeling that there are still more people looking at the question in case there is actual code visible (even as an image) as if there is nothing visible except a link that has to be opened.

Comment: @languitar Images of code simply don't belong on SO. If the OP won't post the code as text, the link will have to do. The plain text link wastes less screen space (that image is really large on small screens, eg on mobile devices), and the plain text link consumes less bandwidth. If people are really curious they can click the link.

Answer (score 1):

your code line:
replace

```
if a == "Yes" or "yes"
```

to

```
if a == "Yes" or a == "yes"
```

Comment: Please don't answer basic questions like this without doing a search for possible duplicates first.

Comment: @PM2Ring Noted.